# Why is it giving me a "method call expected" error?

Tags: java, methods

I have a method that checks out an item to the current patron of my library,

```
public void checkOut(int index) {
        currPatron.items(currPatron.items.size()) = results.get(index);
    }
```

When I hover over "currPatron.items(currPatron.items.size())" it gives me and error saying it expects a method call, why? Its a void method that changes things, and I'm giving it the item array of the current patron to change

This is how currPatron is set

```
public void setPatron(int index) {
        currPatron = patrons.get(index + 1);
    }
```

This is when items is made

```
public class Patron implements Printable {

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList;
```

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve].  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
currPatron.items(currPatron.items.size()) = results.get(index);
```

This is an assignment.

The left-hand side of an assignment has to be either a variable (`i = 0`), a field access (`i.j = 0`) or an array element access (`i[0] = 0`).

Your left-hand side is a method invocation, which isn't allowed.

To set the item in the list, use `set`:

```
currPatron.items.set(currPatron.items.size(), results.get(index));
```